# Possible errata in Head First: Javascript (unless I'm an assumptive rookie)

Tags: javascript, function, object, alert, console.log

I am working through the objects Chapter in Head First Javascript, typing out every example along the way. Halfway through the chapter I came to this section of code explaining functions inside objects:

```
var car = {
  make: 'Chevy',
  model: 'Bel-Air',
  year: 1957,
  color: 'red',
  drive: function() {
    alert.log("Zoom-Zoom");
  }
};
```

Emphasis here is on `alert.log`. Is that a typo, or am I assuming wrong? A lot of the book uses `console.log` in its examples. I've never seen `alert.log` and even googling and stackoverflow led to dead ends. I ran the code in my browser and kept receiving errors until I eventually changed `alert.log` to `alert` and the code ran just fine.

Comment: Yes that's almost certainly intended to be either `alert()` or `console.log()`.

Comment: I also checked the errata page on O'Reilly and there was no sign of this. I'll see if I can alert() them....

Comment: unless you have implemented your own alert.log function Pointy is 100% right :P

Comment: Ya this came straight out of the book, the first example showing objects with methods inside.